# react-native-side-menu "open on button click"

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I am making a react native application for iOS, I used react-native-side-menu library for side menu in my current app. I want to open it when button clicked on my screen (not scrolling from left end).

Any kind of help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[An example](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-side-menu/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.js) is actually provided in the github repo:

The part that should interest you is this one:

```
render() {
    const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;

    return (
      <SideMenu
        menu={menu}
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        onChange={(isOpen) => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            To get started, edit index.ios.js
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
            Cmd+Control+Z for dev menu
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            Current selected menu item is: {this.state.selectedItem}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.toggle()}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/vKRaKDX.png', width: 32, height: 32, }} />
        </Button>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
```

The Button here should toggle the menu. Of course, you should look at the entire code, including particularly updateMenuState() and toggle() functions.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks, let me look in to this.+1

Comment: Please validate the answer if it worked for you!

Comment: Not working, still getting error with Push props.